# select with ng-options, how to initialize with a field already selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I have this code:

 **View:**

```
<select 
        ng-model="filterList" 
        ng-options="data.name for data in filter_options">
</select>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.filter_options = [
        {id: 1, name: 'User'},
        {id: 2, name: 'Option 2'},
        {id: 3, name: 'Option 3'}
];
```

When I first enter the controller, in the select there is nothing and the user MUST have to select something. 
I tried to pass

```
$scope.filterList = {id: 1, name: 'User'};
```

but the select field remains empty.

I want that the option "User" is already select when I enter the controller. Is that duable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `track by` in such cases, where it tracking changes based on `data.id`.

```
<select ng-model="filterList" 
   ng-options="data.name for data in filter_options track by data.id">
</select>
```

> **NOTE:** `track by` would harm if you are using with `select as`

[**Demo Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/vyxU7jPy7m7IToN5XRf9?p=preview)

---

The other way is you could select you could do

```
$scope.filterList = $scope.filter_options[0];
```

Comment: Well this works just fine! Thanks a lot for the rapid answer

Comment: @MattiaPettenuzzo no problem, glad to hear that it helped you, Thanks :)